# Performing Geoprocessing SQL Queries in QGIS from a PostGIS Database

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoprocessing, sql

This may be a dumb question, but is there way to run a PostGIS geoprocessing SQL query in QGIS? Specifically, I am thinking of running SQLs such as ST_Union, ST_Split etc etc.

I have tried the following SQL in the QGIS PostGIS Query Editor without any luck, while the query worked in PostGIS.

```
SELECT covtype, ST_Multi(ST_Union(f.the_geom)) as sGeom
INTO testLCC
FROM lcc2000_001k AS f
GROUP BY covtype;

SELECT populate_geometry_columns
('testLCC'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE testLCC ADD CONSTRAINT pkid PRIMARY KEY(covtype);
```

Comment: I had this problem when I initially started out with QGIS as well. The reason the query does not work within QGIS is because the Query editor treats the area which you can edit as an SQL _WHERE_ clause. Take a look at Mapperz solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want **PgQuery for QGIS**

[image]

Can be downloaded via Fetch Python Plugins in QGIS and filter for pgquery

Comment: I have been playing with the plugin and have not been able to make some of the functionality to work, specifically the ability to double-click on a function or a table to add to the query.  Does anyone know if there is a limitation while using the plugin with Windows7 64-bit on QGIS v1.8?

Comment: Running on a Windows 7 64bit with postgis on localhost with QGIS 1.8 no issues.