# clip one layer with the current map layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, clip

I work in a little companie where the main goal of employees in GIS is to have a quick view of the issues on a study area.

It would be very useful to have a tool wich clip all the layers of the current map extent with the study area.

I made a quick search in ogr tools but I didn't find the appropriate one. Plus, I think that ogr can't work automatically with the current layers.

So I think the solution is Pyqgis but I have no skills in Python.

Is there an existing tool ? Any suggestions to find the simpliest way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What format is your data in? And do you have SQL skills? If you had your data in PostGIS you could use PostGIS query layers.

Comment: I'm using Spatialite through QSpatialite. I have very basic skills in SQL but I didn't see a "Clip" function in Spatialite.

Comment: You can use an Intersection query to return the area that intersects the study area and the other layers. http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.0/spatialite2_sql.html (I haven't actually tried it using spatialite with QGIS but this would be the function you need)

Answer (score 4):

More specifically, if you have in spatialite a polygon layer "study_area" and another polygon layer "issue", then you would do:

## Create a new table for the clipped issue

```
CREATE TABLE issue_clipped (pk_uid integer primary key autoincrement, 
   issue_name text,
   <any additional fields you need from the issue table> )

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('issue_clipped','geometry',<the CRS id>, 'POLYGON', 'XY');
```

Now populate the new issue_clipped table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO issue_clipped (issue_name, geometry)
SELECT issue_name, ST_INTERSECTION(issue.geometry, study_area.geometry)
FROM issue, study_area
WHERE ST_Intersects(issue.geometry, study_area.geometry);
```

Comment: Thanks James S and Micha for the advices but I'm not sure to understand. My aim is to clip multiple layers with one. But St_Intersection takes only two layers in arguments. Micha, I didn't understand what is the "issue_clipped" table that you create before the intersection. Will it receive all the clip results ? Do I need to put the multiple tables in the FROM ?

Comment: You need to run a query for each layer you want to clip/intersect with your study area table. You could also run the queries in QGIS in DB Managers SQL window. That way they would be a query layer in the QGIS project, without creating new tables in your database - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54738/qgis-using-postgis-can-i-define-a-layer-using-sql/54743#54743

Comment: The issue_clipped table is the new table, clipped to the study area. As James pointed out, you'll havea to run this query multiple times for each "issue" layer.

Comment: So what is the benefit over "intersection" tool in the vector menu ? It is not an automated process...

Comment: It is not automated, but what is preventing you from automating this? Or from automating the intersection tool?