# How to add a PostgreSQL query table to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, spatial-query

I have queried my database with the following:

```
SELECT tlblocation.id, tlblocation.geom
FROM "Municipalities_NL", tlblocation, tlbvenueactiveperiod
WHERE st_within(tlblocation.geom, "Municipalities_NL".geom) 
AND "Municipalities_NL".gemeentena::text = 'Amsterdam'::text 
AND tlbvenueactiveperiod.date_opened::text >= '1900-01-01'::text 
AND tlbvenueactiveperiod.date_opened::text <= '1910-01-01'::text;
```

How do I add the output table to QGIS?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54738/qgis-using-postgis-can-i-define-a-layer-using-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- PostgreSQL execute and load SQL

> This algorithm performs a SQL database query on a PostGIS database
> connected to QGIS and loads the query results as a new layer.

- Or check the box "Load as new layer" in DB Manager

[image]