# QGIS crashing when trying to open PostGIS layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to open a fairly large dataset from a postgres database in QGIS. The table contains over 100 million rows, and it about 60gb in size.

When I try to open this table in QGIS (have tried 2.8 and 2.14) it instantly crashes. It doesn't even try to open it. QGIS just locks up completely, no memory usage, no CPU or network activity.

I've tried zooming in to a small area before trying to load the data, but it does the same thing. Also, similar, smaller datasets open fine in the same way.

I was wondering if anyone has had a similar issue? Do we know if there is a limit to the size of a dataset that QGIS will handle from postgres?

Comment: Try adding a LIMIT 10000 - 1000000 to the amount you are trying to load see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28545/performing-geoprocessing-sql-queries-in-qgis-from-a-postgis-database. or use a bounding box sql query

Comment: @Mapperz is it possible there is some data corruption on the geometry?  If so, then LIMIT could help identify the corrupt rows.

Comment: @ kttii the data is good, it has been used elsewhere, just QGIS that won't open it.

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, I'll give that a try and comment back if it works